# Cannot find module 'js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm-install

After adding a request I've got such error. I tried *npm install js* and adding *var js = require("js")* in my app.js file, but it didn't help at all. I run an express server on my localhost.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at new View (E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\app.js:201:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\me\univercity\ais_node\cashdesk\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

This is the request I've added

```
app.get("/category/:id", function(req, res){
    var id = parseInt(req.params.id.charAt(1));
    itemsCopy = items.filter(function(el){
        console.log(el);
        return el.category.find(c => c == id);
    });

    console.log(itemsCopy);
    res.render("index.js", {items: itemsCopy});
});
```

npm install js didn't help.
Here is my *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

It seems that the problem in those js functions *filter* and *find*, but I have no idea how to make them understandable for Node.

**UPDATE:**
It is how items look like. I need to filter them by category. I want to show only those ones, who have filtering value in field *category*.

```
items = [
    {
        name: "Lorem",
        price: 16,
        descr: "This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.",
        warranity: true,
        warranity_length: 6,
        warranity_rules: "Do not put under water",
        category: [0]
    },
    {
        name: "ipsum",
        price: 67,
        descr: "This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.",
        warranity: true,
        warranity_length: 6,
        category: [0,1]

    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the file (complete code) you are importing that lib?

Comment: I have a hard time believing you need a dependency like `"js": "^0.1.0"`.  Q: Was this in your original "package.json"?  If so, where did you get it from?  Q: What happens if you remove any `"js": "^0.1.0"` (and remove any "require"  imports for `js` in your app)?  Do you get any errors?  If so, please post them.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your full code per above comment. What are you using this library for? Not familiar with it and npm turns up one that parses JSON. Seems unnecessary to create another dependency if it can be done w express. Why not find a suitable alternative.

Comment: As I said before, I've got this error after adding code in *app.js*. I've tried to fix the problem by running ```npm install js``` and adding "require" imports for ```js``` in my app. Npm command added ``` "js": "^0.1.0"```.  But the problem was still the same. Nothing changes if  I remove those parts of code.

Comment: *items* is an array and I just need it to be filtred.I want to get only those objects, who have filtering value in field *category*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a typo here. *index.js* instead of *index.ejs* in *res.render()*. This one is correct

```
app.get("/category/:id", function(req, res){
    var id = parseInt(req.params.id.charAt(1));
    itemsCopy = items.filter(function(el){
        console.log(el);
        return el.category.find(c => c == id);
    });

    console.log(itemsCopy);
    res.render("index.ejs", {items: itemsCopy});
});
``
```